# Ubuntu 12.10 Installation type

Tags: installation

I am new to linux. i am trying to install ubuntu 12.10 on my parallels virtual machine on Macbook. 
it is asking for the installation type where it says "Erase disk and install ubuntu" i dont understand what option i should select here. 
if i select this option "Erase disc and install ubuntu" will it erase everything on the harddisk.
i just want to install it on virtual machine so that i could use both mack and ubuntu.
please help

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with parallels virtual machine. Is it same type of solution like virtual machine and vmware? Do you need to create a virtual machine & disk for this installation?

If so, erase and install ubuntu will erase the virtual disc. Not the actual hard disk.